# Aspectual pairs with one reflexive

Tags: лексикон, вид

Normally a reflexivity of a verb stays the same regardless of aspect (not talking about semantic derivation). But I have learned three exceptions to this rule already:

> **станови́ться – стать** (but: ста́ться *разг.*)
>
> **сади́ться – сесть**
>
> **соску́читься – скуча́ть** (по кому́-то / о ко́м-то)

I can only think of one example in Polish and always considered it an oddity, so I am wondering if this is a wider phenomenon in Russian. Are there other pairs of verbs like these?

Comment: Ложиться - лечь?

Comment: @user75619 I am not sure, I usually think of the pair to be ложи́тся – положи́ться, but it fits.

Comment: Also how about расходиться - разойтись?

Comment: @user75619 But they are both reflexive. I am seeking examples of verbs when one is reflexive and one is not ;-)

Comment: Indeed! My mistake...

Comment: *скучать по кому* is a modern deviation, correct case is Prepositional *по ком*

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка *скучать о ком/чём* (скучать о городе) would be more correct for Prepositional.

Comment: Prepositional is governed by both pronouns **о** and **по**, but the one of the two which is more applicable to the verb ***скучать*** is **по**. Dictionaries and grammar books do also mention **о** but i don't think i have come across many examples of its usage, and to me personally it sounds off. We can do a **proper** Google search to gauge frequency - ***скучал о*** - a little over 6000, ***скучал по*** - exactly 485 000

Comment: and out of the 3 pairs you mention in 1 the roles are reversed, reflexive is perfective

Comment: What is the Polish example?

Comment: @Sergey Slepov I actually can't recall atm, it wasn't an obvious one :\

Comment: ***соскучиться - скучать*** may actually not be an aspectual pair, because each of them has unique aspectual counterpart, to wit ***соскучиваться*** and ***поскучать*** respectively

Comment: Interesting! Two of my dictionaries list them as a pair... I will theck this out!

Answer (score 3):

Regular imperfective counterparts for *стать, сесть, лечь* should have been **ставать, *седать, *легать*, but those forms have fallen out of use as standalone words in the codified language, though they continue to exist as roots: *встать / вставать, присесть / приседать, налечь / налегать*.

These forms have been [suppleted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suppletion) with the reflexive causatives: *-становить, -садить, -ложить* are causatives meaning "make stand", "make sit" and "make lie", respectively, and when used with a reflexive postfix they mean "make oneself stand", "make oneself sit" and "make oneself lie".

I can't think of any more suppletive imperfective verbs with this exact paradigm (causative + reflexive) in Russian, but there are other paradigms: vowel alternation (*умирать / умереть, собирать / собрать*); stress alternation (*насыпа́ть / насы́пать, нареза́ть / наре́зать*); good old replacement with etymologically unrelated roots (*ловить / поймать, брать / взять*) etc.

Comment: for all 3 verbs in question Ukrainian has retained genuine aspectual counterparts

Answer (score 2):

It sounds logical :)

**Ложиться - лечь**

Pay attention that статься has the meaning of случиться, to happen.

> при-/за-/на-/всмотреться - смотреть
>
> дождаться - ждать
>
> при-/за-/на-/вслушаться - слушать
>
> наесться - есть (and there is a possibility to express having done
>   enough of anything with the prefix на- and the reflexive particle -ся)
>
> приесться - надоесть

...?

Actually, I would separate them in a way. Лечь, стать, сесть as the verbs of physical situation, and скучать, ждать, смотреть, etc. as feelings.

Comment: "приесться - надоесть" are both perfective.

Comment: Problem with those is that they aren't really aspectual pairs :( Aspectual pair is when two verbs only differ in aspect, not in the shade of meaning they have. наесться & съесть are both perfective, but they aren't equivalent semantically ;) But words of movement and location do seem to be weird in terms of reflexivity.

Comment: illustration - perfective of ***ждать*** is ***подождать***, imperfective of ***дождаться*** is ***дожидаться***, imperfective of ***надоесть*** is ***надоедать***, while that of ***приесться*** is ***приедаться***